# Ubuntu Server Port 80 not reachable/closed

Tags: 12.04, port-forwarding

I am running Ubuntu server 12.04 with Apache2.

My port 80 is not reachable and closed. Any idea how can I open it so I can access to my web admin?

I noticed that port 80 is reachable under LAN, but its not able to reach outside of LAN even I had done port forwarding.

What should I do?

Thanks.

Comment: How do you know your port is closed? Any result? Please include output of `sudo iptables -L`

Comment: I downloaded a software from portforward.com to check is my port is reachable or not. Then I got the result its close. Below is my result of iptables -L

root@server:~# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Comment: What about `sudo ufw allow 80`?

Comment: @BharadwajRaju UFW generates IPtables rules, which would have shown up in user1343112's answer if it was enabled. Also, port 80 being reachable on the LAN is a very good sign that UFW is not blocking this.

Answer (score 0):

To access webmin you have to use the port 10000 with https like this: `https://localhost:10000/`

Moreover if you want to change Apache port

Open /etc/apache2/ports.conf file, enter:

```
$ gksu gedit /etc/apache2/ports.conf
```

To make the server accept connections on both port 8010, enter:

```
Listen 8010
```

To make the server accept connections on both port 80 and port 8010, use:

```
Listen 80
Listen 8010
```

Now restart apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

and try.

---

Comment: I had done this process. But still fail.

Comment: https://localhost:10000  have you try this

Comment: u mean add localhost:10000 into my /etc/apache2/ports.conf?

Comment: no run in browser

Comment: be sure to run https not http

Comment: Result: webpage is not available. What should I do next?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13162/discussion-between-user1343112-and-maythux)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned Port 80 is reachable from LAN but from not WAN with configuration of port forwarding.

When you configure Port forwarding, you must to check that gateway is configured as default route.

You can check routes by `route -n`.
Make your gateway default route. 
For example if gateway address is 192.168.1.1. You can make it as default route.

```
sudo route add default gw 192.168.1.1
```